# Reach all nodes in a graph datastructure

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, graph, graph-algorithm

Say, I am having a graph object with list of vertices and edges respectively. G={V,E}

`G={[3, 4, 1, 2, 5, 6],[3->4, 1->2, 1->5, 5->4, 5->6]}`

Assuming the graph is `unweighted and undirected` I am in the need to find whether all the `Vertices are interconnected with eachother` i.e. no individual nodes or interconnected nodes are isolated.

```
1 -- 2

|

5 -- 4 -- 3

| 

6
```

Is it related to traversing the graph using DFS or BFS ? Please help me through this, Thanks.

Comment: If the graph is undirected, DFS/BFS will give you all nodes reachable from a given starting node. The nodes not visited during this run are not connected to this component. Read the wiki page about [connected components](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory)) for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this result using [spanning tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanning_tree) also. In wiki it is defined as :

`In the mathematical field of graph theory, a spanning tree T of a connected, undirected graph G is a tree composed of all the vertices and some (or perhaps all) of the edges of G.`

[image: SPanning Tree]

Figure : Spanning tree (Source: [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:4x4_grid_spanning_tree.svg))

If you want to find [minimum spanning tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree) [Prim's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm) can be a good choice.
Example of code snippet :

```
MST-Prim(G,r)
01 for each vertex u element of G.V
02    u.key :=infinity
03    u.parent := NIL
04 r.key := 0
05 init(Q, G.V)   // Q is a priority queue
06 while not isEmpty(Q)
07    u := extractMin(Q)   // add u to T
08    for each v element of u.adj do
09        if v element of Q and w(u,v) < v.key then
10        v.key := w(u,v)
11          modifyKey(Q,v)
12          v.parent := u
```

UPDATE:

Explanation of Prim's Algorithm can be found [here](http://datastructuresnotes.blogspot.com/2009/03/prim-jarniks-algorithm-for-extract.html).

More info about minimum spanning tree is available [here](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/161/960206.html).

Comment: Isn't that a bit complicated if the OP just wants to check if the graph is connected?

Comment: @Baz yup , that's true. But it is one of the most popular algorithm for this purpose. Sooner or later one have to learn this if s/he wants to code problems of graphs.

Comment: A spanning tree of a connected graph G can also be defined as a maximal set of edges of G that contains no cycle, or `as a minimal set of edges that connect all vertices`.-[Spanning tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanning_tree)

So this is actually a valid answer of OP's question.

Comment: Who said it wasn't a valid answer?

Comment: Most probably who downvoted and clarified no reason for that :)

Comment: Fair enough, let's equate that: +1 :D

Answer (score 1):

1. Take one verticle as start point
2. Launch BFS/DFS from that verticle
3. Check if all verticles were visited

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the problem can be solved using BFS/DFS. 
You can choose any searching algorithm among these two and any starting node and if by the search technique ( DFS or BFS ) you do not reach to at least one node it means that there are one or more disconnected components and some individual nodes or interconnected nodes are isolated. But this does not tell you that how many disconnected components are present, for this you have to again start the traversal using some other non visited node.

Answer (score 0):

A simmilar question has been answered in [Algorithm for counting connected components of a graph in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005206/algorithm-for-counting-connected-components-of-a-graph-in-python).

Since you are asking if the graph is connected, you add the following function to the script:

```
def isGraphConnected(graph):
    return get_connected_components_number(graph)==1
```

Comment: His question is more about the idea of the implementation and not as much for the actual implementation. The code can be easily transferred into java.

Comment: Yes, if one understands python :) I would not assume this in general.

Comment: I agree with you :) But I consider python to be almost pseudo-code. Maybe OP should comment on this.